# ¿error: implicit declaration of function 'vfs_fat_mkdir'?

Tags: c

Estoy intentando compilar en esp idf que es el framework del micro controlador de esspressif para esp32

error: implicit declaration of function 'vfs_fat_mkdir' [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]

vfs_fat_mkdir();

al parecer este error se debe a que generalemente no esta definida la cabecera de la funcion pero al revisar el codigo aparece lo siguente

```
#ifdef CONFIG_VFS_SUPPORT_DIR
static int vfs_fat_stat(void* ctx, const char * path, struct stat * st);
static int vfs_fat_link(void* ctx, const char* n1, const char* n2);
static int vfs_fat_unlink(void* ctx, const char *path);
static int vfs_fat_rename(void* ctx, const char *src, const char *dst);
static DIR* vfs_fat_opendir(void* ctx, const char* name);
static struct dirent* vfs_fat_readdir(void* ctx, DIR* pdir);
static int vfs_fat_readdir_r(void* ctx, DIR* pdir, struct dirent* entry, struct dirent** out_dirent);
static long vfs_fat_telldir(void* ctx, DIR* pdir);
static void vfs_fat_seekdir(void* ctx, DIR* pdir, long offset);
static int vfs_fat_closedir(void* ctx, DIR* pdir);
static int vfs_fat_mkdir(void* ctx, const char* name, mode_t mode);
static int vfs_fat_rmdir(void* ctx, const char* name);
static int vfs_fat_access(void* ctx, const char *path, int amode);
static int vfs_fat_truncate(void* ctx, const char *path, off_t length);
static int vfs_fat_ftruncate(void* ctx, int fd, off_t length);
static int vfs_fat_utime(void* ctx, const char *path, const struct utimbuf *times);
#endif // CONFIG_VFS_SUPPORT_DIR
```

lo cual me hace pensar que necesito definir CONFIG_VFS_SUPPORT_DIR, pero al hacerlo solo me avisa que ya esta previamente definido en un archivo kconfig